# MS Graph API - certain operations on user immediately after it has been invited fail

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When performing certain actions on a user object immediately after the user has been created by a `POST` request to the `invitation` endpoint an error response is returned:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Directory_ObjectNotFound",
        "message": "Unable to read the company information from the directory.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "c8956ca4-ebbf-43eb-9fa1-266b9f476b30",
            "date": "2018-10-11T09:44:44"
        }
    }
}
```

The actions I have found not to work are:
1) `PATCH` request that sets `accountEnabled` to `false`
2) `DELETE` request

`GET` requests for the user work. Updating (`PATCH`) other properties of the user also works.

This behaviour is only for **invited/guest users** and only **if the requests are made immediately after the creation of the user**. If the requests are made after a 10 second delay they are successful. Making a `PATCH` request that updates other properties of the user before making the other requests also seems to fix the problem.

This problem can be illustrated in this Postman run:
[image]

Is this a bug or is it expected that some actions have to be delayed or another PATCH request made before them when working with a user that has just been invited (`invitation` object posted) and if so are these actions documented somewhere?

Comment: I am having the same issue, except I have accountEnabled set to true when the PATCH request is sent. The other weird thing is that even after 20 seconds of waiting, some users still aren't updated.

Comment: @RinaldsR, may I ask how you worked around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if so are these actions documented somewhere?

I have not found official docs on this.

> Is this a bug or is it expected that some actions have to be delayed
>   or another PATCH request made before them when working with a user
>   that has just been invited

But it should be normal behavior but not bug.

Operation in Azure Services/Product are asynchronous,they aren't real-time(Include the Azure Active Directory). Some even require 24 hours / 72 hours to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still seems weird that making a PATCH request that updates other properties before making a PATCH request that setts the 'accountEnabled' property to false solves the problem. But I get the point that you just shouldn't always rely on the operations being complete as soon as you receive a response so I'll mark the answer as accepted.